# Obtaining an AUC value from the KNN function

Tags: r, knn, auc

I am using the `class` package in order to use the KNN algorithm. I am also using the `ROCR` package to calculate the AUC value.

`knn_one<-knn(train, test, train$Digit, k=1)`

To calculate the AUC value for another method, e.g. classification trees, I used these series of commands:

```
treeTrain_Pred<-predict(Tree_Train, test , type = "prob")[,2]
Pred<-prediction(treeTrain_Pred, test$Digit)
Perf<-performance(Pred, "auc")
Perf@y.values[[1]]
```

However, when I try

```
knn_one = predict(knn_one, test, type="prob")[,2]
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

How can I fix this and obtain an AUC value for my KNN function?

Comment: You should convert your target variable into character.

Comment: Hi, I tried that:
knn_one<-as.character(knn_one). However, I now get the message:
"Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "character""

Comment: It is weird, It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

There is no predict method for knn models, instead you train and receive predictions as part of a single call. Example on sonar data:

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
```

create data partition:

```
set.seed(1)
tr_ind <- sample(1:nrow(Sonar), 150)
train <- Sonar[tr_ind,]
test <- Sonar[-tr_ind,]

mod <- class::knn(cl = train$Class,
                  test = test[,1:60],
                  train = train[,1:60],
                  k = 5,
                  prob = TRUE)
```

Now the probability of the predictions are in:

```
attributes(mod)$prob

library(pROC)

roc(test$Class, attributes(mod)$prob)
#output
Call:
roc.default(response = test$Class, predictor = attributes(mod)$prob)

Data: attributes(mod)$prob in 30 controls (test$Class M) < 28 cases (test$Class R).
Area under the curve: 0.4667

plot(roc(test$Class, attributes(mod)$prob),
     print.thres = T,
     print.auc=T)
```

[image]

lets try with k = 4

```
mod <- class::knn(cl = train$Class,
                  test = test[,1:60],
                  train = train[,1:60],
                  k = 4,
                  prob = TRUE)

plot(roc(test$Class, attributes(mod)$prob),
     print.thres = T,
     print.auc = T,
     print.auc.y = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I've read that the AUC value should be between 0.5 and 1. Mind you, when I apply your method to my data, I get an AUC value of 0.5 but I'm not sure if there is another scaled being used here...

Comment: @The Statistician Magician when the AUC is less than 0.5 it just means the prediction is worse than random guess, which is the case here since the model predicted all "R" while there were 28 "R" and 30 "M" in the test set. KNN does not perform very well in multiple dimensions (Sonar has 60). The model can be improved by choosing  a better k.

Comment: Ah ok. I see. I'm just wondering -- my dependent variable is binary (0 or 1) - would that affect the calculation here? Just thinking about the "prob = TRUE" argument...

Comment: to create a ROC curve you need predicted probabilities and not predicted classes.